# How to convert a matlab figure to a latex code? (not to a graphic)

Tags: matlab, matlab2tikz, convert

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I want to convert my matlab figure to a latex code (no graphic). I want the latex code. I know its possible. But i dont know how. Of course i can also export my matlab figure to an eps or pdf! But i need from this matlab figure the latex code. i hope you understand my problem. thank you in advance.

Comment: you could use `matlab2tikz`, if you don't want to use eps or pdf files. mb this helps: [http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/)

Comment: this blog is also useful: https://tomlankhorst.nl/matlab-to-latex-with-matlab2tikz/

Answer (score 3):

It is highly recommended to use [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz) for this task.
You need to download the package and after plotting your figure in Matlab, you should run the matlab2tikz.m function by:

```
matlab2tikz('YourLatexFile.tex');
```

Then you can add `YourLatexFile.tex` into your LaTeX source code, for example by using `\input{YourLatexFile.tex}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  %% the following commands are sometimes needed
  \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
  \usepackage{grffile}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  %% you may also want the following commands
  %\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
  %\newlength\figureheight
  %\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
  \input{YourLatexFile.tex}
\end{document}
```

Also there are suitable documentation and examples in their [Github](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/tree/master/src) page.